# Why do I have to use SomeRandomString.equals("something") instead of SomeRandomString == "something" in Java?

Tags: java, android, string, algorithm, equals

I'm relatively new to Java so I'm kind of lost here. Is it wrong when you are trying to compare two strings just use the identical symbol "==" instead of using a method for checking if two strings are identical. Because for what I have tried the first option doesn't work and I'm very curious on the reason behing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java when you use `String`, you work with **reference**.

```
String one = "one";
String two = "two";

if(one == two)
    // true if references `one` and `two` point to the same object

if(one.equals(two))
    // true if strings `one` and `two` are equals (it could be to different objects)
```